# How to solve constraint problem where variables must be one of a discrete set of values in OR-Tools?

Tags: python, or-tools, constraint-programming

My problem looks like this: A movie theatre is showing a set of n films over a 5 day period. Each movie has a corresponding IMBD score. I want to watch one movie per day over the 5 day period, maximising the cumulative IMBD score whilst making sure that I watch the best movies first (i.e. Monday's movie will have a higher score than Tuesday's movie, Tuesday's higher than Wednesday's etc.). An extra constraint if that the theatre doesn't show every movie every day. For example.

Showings:
Monday showings: Sleepless in Seattle, Multiplicity, Jaws, The Hobbit
Tuesday showings: Sleepless in Seattle, Kramer vs Kramer, Jack Reacher
Wednesday showings: The Hobbit, A Star is Born, Joker
etc.

Scores:
Sleepless in Seattle: 7.0
Multiplicity: 10
Jaws: 9.2
The Hobbit: 8.9
A Star is Born: 6.2
Joker: 5.8
Kramer vs Kramer: 8.7
etc.

The way I've thought about this is that each day represents a variable: a,b,c,d,e and we are maximising (a+b+c+d+e) where each variable represents a day of the week and to make sure that I watch the movies in descending order in terms of IMBD rank I would add a constraint that a > b > c > d > e. However using the linear solver as far as I can tell you cannot specify discrete values, just a range as the variables will be chosen from a continuous range (in an ideal world I think the problem would look like "solve for a,b,c,d,e maximising their cumulative sum, while ensuring a>b>c>d>e where a can be this set of possible values, b can be this set of possible values etc.). I'm wondering if someone can point me in the right direction of which OR-Tools solver (or another library) would be best for this problem?

I tried to use the GLOP linear solver to solve this problem but failed. I was expecting it to solve for a,b,c,d, and e but I couldn't write the necessary constraints with this paradigm.

Comment: You need a mi/cp solver. Look at CP-SAT as it supports discrete domains. As it is in integer only. You will need to scale up 7.8 to 78.

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you have any advice on how to set a soft constraint so the resultant movies (if feasible) are ordered so that the highest rated ones are generally viewed first? One solution I thought of is to have the later days' ratings be sequentially scaled (e.g. if Monday and Tuesday are showing the exact same movies then Monday's ratings would be: [86, 90, 50, 12], Tuesday's ratings: [43, 45, 25, 6]) to try force it to greedily fill the earlier slots with higher rated movies)

Comment: Maybe look at https://github.com/google/or-tools/discussions/3640